# Convert SOAP XML String to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, web-services, soap

**I want to convert SOAP XML to Java Object without using xsd files and other stuff. I generate SOAP XML using POJO classes, @Xml annotations. What I want is to somehow deserialize String to not Envelope.class Object, but NumberToWords.class Object.**

**And by the way I didn't wanna have ns2:/xmlns="" stuff, that's why I used final static String as @XmlAttribute`s instead of namespace initializations.**

Here are my classes >>>

```
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "soap:Envelope")
public class Envelope {

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "xmlns:soap"
    )
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private static final String xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

    @XmlElement(
            name = "soap:Body"
    )
    private Body body;

    public String printBody() {
        return body.toString();
    }

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Body {

    @XmlElement(name = "NumberToWords")
    private NumberToWords numberToWords;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private Name name;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NumberToWords {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
    private final static String xmlns = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/";

    @XmlElement(name = "ubiNum")
    private Integer ubiNum;

}
```

Mapper Class which gets Marshaller Bean from another config class, but I decided to not add it here.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EnvelopeMapper {

    private final Marshaller marshaller;


    @SneakyThrows
    public String getXml(NumberToWords numberToWords) {
        Envelope envelope = Envelope.builder()
                .body(
                        Body.builder()
                                .numberToWords(numberToWords)
                                .build())

                .build();

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        marshaller.marshal(envelope, stringWriter);

        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

**localhost:8080/get-num-xml/123**

```
STRING:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <NumberToWords xmlns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
            <ubiNum>123</ubiNum>
        </NumberToWords>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I call this endpoint it throws an exception.

```
@GetMapping("/get-num-xml/{num}")
public String getNumXml(@PathVariable Integer num) throws JAXBException {
    String xml = envelopeService.getNumberToWords(num);

    NumberToWords numberToWords = (NumberToWords) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

    System.out.println(numberToWords.getUbiNum());

    return envelopeService.getNumberToWords(num);
}

GIVES:
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{}Name>,<{}body>,<{}soap:Envelope>
```

This one is also throws an exception.

```
@GetMapping("/get-num-xml/{num}")
public String getNumXml(@PathVariable Integer num) throws JAXBException, SOAPException, IOException {
    String xml = envelopeService.getNumberToWords(num);
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(NumberToWords.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    NumberToWords rc = (NumberToWords) unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

    return envelopeService.getNumberToWords(num);
}

GIVES:

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/", local:"NumberToWords"). Expected elements are (none)
```

**I don't have a clue how to unmarshal xml, so I hope someone has an answer for this one.**